# Delete lines containing repeated text

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I have a file containing two paths on each line. I want to remove the lines containing the same path twice.

I work on Linux and Solaris. I would like a one-liner in sed or awk or perl.

Example input file:

```
     /usr/lib/libgmp.so.3.3.3 /usr/lib/libgmp.so.3.3.3
     /usr/lib/libxslt.so.1.1.17 /usr/lib/libxslt.so.1.1.17
     /usr/lib/sse2/libgmp.so.3.3.3 /usr/lib/sse2/libgmp.so.3.3.3
     /usr/local/swp-tomcat-6.0/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar /usr/local/swp-tomcat-6.0/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
     /usr/share/doc/libXrandr-1.1.1 /usr/share/doc/libXrandr-1.1.1
     /usr/share/doc/libxslt-1.1.17 /usr/share/doc/libxslt-1.1.17
     /etc/3.3.3.255 /etc/172.17.211.255
     /etc/1.1.1.255 /etc/172.17.213.255
```

Expected output:

```
     /etc/3.3.3.255 /etc/172.17.211.255
     /etc/1.1.1.255 /etc/172.17.213.255
```

Comment: `grep` isn't good? That is the dedicated tool to output lines from a file matching certain condition: `grep -vx '\s*\(\S\+\)\s\+\1\s*' file`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
awk '{ if ($1 != $2 ) print $1" "$2; }' file
```

Just replace file for the appropriate file.

Or as @manatwork mentioned in the comments and simpler

```
awk '$1!=$2' file
```

Comment: Why not just `awk '$1!=$2' file`?

Comment: I was not aware it could be that simple. :/

Answer (score 2):

You can express repeated text in `grep`'s regexps (this is an extension to the mathematical notion of regular expression).

```
grep -v '^ *\([^ ][^ ]*\)  *\1 *$'
```

`[^ ][^ ]*` matches one or more non-space character. The backslash-parentheses make this a group, and `\1` means “the same text as the first group”.

Comment: Except from being an alternative, can you give an argument why one should use `grep` over `awk` here?

Comment: @Bernhard Both are good methods. More people know grep basics than awk basics, but on the other hand the awk code is clearer, so I think there's no clear winner.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/(\S+)\s\1/d' file
```

Comment: Though untested, your (elegant!) solution should also work in non-GNU `sed` when written like this: `sed '/\(\S\+\)\s\1/d' file`. Just a little more escaping needed, and you'll be 100% compatible everywhere.